# Как прочитать и изменить код открытой страницы с помощью расширения chrome

Tags: chrome-extension

Делаю свое 1 расширение chrome, сделал xhr запрос на сайт, смог получить от туда данные. Но я хотел бы теперь получить данные с сайта на котором авторизован пользователь, тут уже xhr не поможет. А еще хотел бы сравнить данные с этого сайта и данные полученные xhr, и выдать результат прямо на странице пользователя. Данные эти - цена товара, на 1 площадке она 1, на другой другая, и надо бы найти выгодное предложение.

Comment: content скрипт расширения хрома имеет полный доступ к открытой странице (если адрес сайта явно указан в манифесте для данного контент скрипта). И вам не надо самому делать никаких запросов куда либо. Вы просто заходите в браузере на целевую страницу, он ее сам открывает и при этом ваше расширение имеет к ней доступ. Т.е. контент скрипт обращается к ней как будто он на ней загружен, с помощью любых функций работы с DOM

Comment: Что-то не понял, вот добавил я сайт в манифест, как дальше в js мне получить этот код?

Comment: Написали куда именно ? Надо описать блок "content_scripts" в котором указываются маски страниц на которых должен запускаться скрипт и указывается этот самый скрипт. Внутри скрипта вы имеете полный доступ к объекту document и можете делать с ним что угодно, точно так же как будто ваш скрипт находится внутри страницы (ну почти так, там есть несколько тонких моментов связанных с безопасностью)

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts  там внизу есть ссылки на примеры с готовыми тестовыми расширениями

Comment: "content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["тут указал нужную страницу"],
  "js": ["popup.js"]
 }],
Дальше в popup.js я сделал document.getElementsById('how_to').html(), на сайте есть такое ид, но мне ничего не выдает. Вообще ничего. popup.js подключен в popup.html, и срабатывает при нажатии на расширение. Когда сделал отдельный js не привязанный к html, он вообще не запустился.

Comment: Во первых popup и content это севершенно разные скрипты. popup не имеет доступа к странице. к ней имеет доступ только content. Во вторых, что вы ожидаете получить от `document.getElementsById('how_to').html()`, особенно учитывая, что в document нет функции с именем `getElementsById`, есть только `getElementById` (без s), во вторых у найденного элемента нет функции `html()`, есть свойство `html`, но оно пустое, текст тега можно получить через свойство `innerHTML`. И тогда вы получите текст, но вам его надо еще куда нибудь вывести, что бы увидеть, например в консоль (console.log())

Comment: Да, уже js забываю) То есть это куда мне надо писать скрипт, чтобы иметь доступ к коду?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доступ к страницам имеют только [content](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) скрипты. Минимальный рабочий пример контент скрипта, выводящего имя пользователя StackOverflow, прочитанное со страницы, после чего меняющий рейтинг на +100500 (не отлаживал, если вы не залогинены. так же может перестать работать если SO поменяет дизайн).

Файл manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Sample content script",
  "version": "0.0.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "*://*.stackoverflow.com/*", "*://stackoverflow.com/*" ],
      "js": [ "js/so.js" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Файл js/so.js (папка js должна быть рядом с манифестом):

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('my-profile')[0].childNodes[1].title);
document.getElementsByClassName('-rep')[0].innerText="+100500";
```

Content скрипты имеют полный доступ к страницам, которые описаны в манифесте. Но обычно не могут при этом обращаться ни к каким сторонним сайтам. Скрипт загружается в момент загрузки страницы и удаляется при выходе с этой страницы. Если требуется обмен информацией с другими сайтами, сохранение информации между посещениями страницы и т.п. дополнительно к нему потребуется background-скрипт, обмениваться информацией с которым можно через [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#method-sendMessage)

Comment: Работает. Еще вопрос, как выдать переменную если она в функции заключена? xhr.onreadystatechange = function(), ведь не я ее вызываю.

Comment: @MrLuckyTomas это сложнее. обычно я внедряю прямо на страницу скрипт, который заменяет функцию на мой вариант, которая помимо своей работы вызывает событие из контент скрипта с передачей нужной информации внутрь.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо. Попробую решить как-то по-другому проблему. Например добавлять в атрибут элемента результат)

Comment: Еще проблемка. Делаю цикл для обработки всех элементов класса, и мне нужно получить их атрибут и передать сам элемент и атрибут в функцию, которая уже обработает. Но, v.attr is not a function. Я выводил в консоль v, и выходил просто код элемента, а когда массив элементов, там не просто код, а jquery тип какой-то. Как тогда работать с элементом?

Comment: Дело в том, что у сайта название предмета в аттрибуте data-title. Я цену с другого сайта сохранил в steam-price. Мне надо сделать цикл, чтобы каждый товар на сайте обработался функцией, которая узнает цену по data-title на другой площадке и добавит на сайте кроме цены этого сайта, цену на другом сайте.

Comment: @MrLuckyTomas `document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].getAttribute('data-title')` номер элемента конечно в цикле перебираете

Comment: Не ищет он у меня через getElementsByTagName, через jquery ищет. Сделал вывод в консоль когда выше, он выдает undefined, класс заменил на нужный. Если не знаешь jquery, я могу создать еще вопрос людям знающим его.

Comment: @MrLuckyTomas Да, так будет лучше. в вопросе обязательно покажите кусок html кода из которого надо доставать. И заодно как в jquery достаете. ну и спросите видимо как будет на обычном JS без библиотек. Не видя всего этого все равно ответить невозможно. И знать jquery что бы понять что делает какой то код и перевести его на чистый JS

Comment: Ту проблему решил. Еще вопрос. На сайте есть страницы, и кнопки назад и вперед. Вот нажимая на них, удаляется содержимое страницы и грузиться новое содержимое. Мне нужно это новое содержимое обработать. Но когда я делаю обработку при клике на кнопку, сначала мой код срабатывает, потом код сайта. То есть еще данные не подгрузились, а мой код уже выполнен. Конечно ему редактировать нечего и тупо грузится след страница без обработки.