# Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Я в отчаянии, оно теперь даже ошибки не выдаёт.
Нужно чтобы расширение меняло 1 символ на другой.
Я уже не знаю что делать, помогите пожалуйста. manifest:

```
{
"name": "Extension",
"description" : "Base Level Extension",
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "cookies",
    "activeTab",
    "tabCapture",
    "<all_urls>"
],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "icons":{
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  },
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2 }
```

background.js:

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "jquery-3.4.1.min.js";
script.onreadystatechange = handler;
script.onload = handler;
body.appendChild(script);

function handler(){
   
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(){
    $("body").children().each(function () {
        $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/B/g,"H") );
    });
    console.log('Done');
})
```

Comment: Работа с документом должна выполняться _из контент-скриптов_, а не фоновых. Также, программные инъекции могут блокироваться CSP - поэтому желательно обходиться без них.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/776811/194569